# Is it possible to use an argument multiple times in a Rust macros with a single instansiation?

Tags: macros, rust

Is it possible to use an argument multiple times in a Rust macro, only having the argument instantiated once?

Take this simple example:

```
macro_rules! squared {
    ($x:expr) => {
        $x * $x
    }
}
```

While this works, if called like `squared!(some_function() + 1)`, the function will be called multiple times. Is there a way to avoid this?

Non-working example:

```
macro_rules! squared {
    ($x:expr) => {
        let y = $x;
        y * y
    }
}
```

Gives a compile error:

```
 error: expected expression, found statement (`let`)
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to explain why your example is "non-working"? [It appears to work for me](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9f89d79b921d6036998e2cabc267c740).

Comment: Noted error in question.

Comment: Did you click my second link that shows your second macro and the fact **that it works**? Could you [edit] your question to show how you are calling the second macro such that it fails? Perhaps you could even [create something on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) that completely reproduces the error? It is 100% expected that you create a [MCVE] when asking questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you're just missing an extra set of braces to contain the expression.

```
macro_rules! squared {
    ($x:expr) => {{
        let y = $x;
        y * y
    }}
}
```

Note that this macro will only work for expressions that have a type that implements `Copy`.